# Google Geolocation API is always returning the same location regardless of cellTower specified

Tags: geolocation, google-geolocation

I'm using the Google Geolocation API to approximate location based on cell towers that are visible.  However, I always get the same location as the result.

Using the following body:

```
{
    "considerIp": false,
    "radioType": "lte",
    "cellTowers": [{
        "signalStrength": -78,
        "cellId": 133978007,
        "mobileNetworkCode": 410,
        "mobileCountryCode": 310,
        "locationAreaCode": 27196
    }]
}
```

Produces the following result:
`{"location": {"lat": 31.968598800000002, "lng": -99.9018131}, "accuracy": 1457406}`

The actual location of that tower/cell is approx (32.783062, 96.795769).  In fact, the cell tower specified is take directly from OpenCellID's database (opencellid.org)

If I then select a tower somewhere else (e.g. Palo Alto)

```
{
    "considerIp": false,
    "radioType": "lte",
    "cellTowers": [{
        "signalStrength": -78,
        "cellId": 84785686,
        "mobileNetworkCode": 480,
        "mobileCountryCode": 311,
        "locationAreaCode": 7943
    }]
}
```

The response is:
`{"location": {"lat": 31.968598800000002, "lng": -99.9018131}, "accuracy": 1457406}`
which is exactly the same.

If I can my public IP (via changing VPN end-point location) the results DO change.  Using the same Palo Alto query but changing from a Texas to Chicago end-node my result changes to:
`{"location": {"lat": 37.09024, "lng": -95.712891}, "accuracy": 1488703}`

It looks like the considerIp=false argument is being ignored and that is only being used instead of the provided cell tower.

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  Apparently if the Content-Type is not being explicitly set to application/json then the body is silently ignored and only the local IP is considered.

I would like to request that Google updates the API response body to include something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Include a flag **"considerIp": false,**,in the request body.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).