# Google Maps Geolocation API with a single Cell Tower very often returns "Error 404 geolocation not found"

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, google-geolocation

I'm using Google Geolocation API to convert a single Cell Tower data to location data. The request is made by a Windows service. Typically it's:

```
{
    "considerIp": "false",
    "cellTowers":
    [
       {
        "cellId": 60711,
        "locationAreaCode": 856,
        "mobileCountryCode": 234,
        "mobileNetworkCode": 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Very often (about 80% of my requests) the response is "Error 404 geolocation not found":

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not Found",
        "domain": "geolocation",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For this reason I was forced to use a similar service provided by Unwiredlabs, that successfully answer to 95% of my requests.
Is it possible that Google cannot resolve 80% of my requests? I don't think so, but I can't understand where I'm wrong.

For testing purpose [cells.csv](http://download.micro-systems.it/download/fd599eaee4b4d81d15cae07c8b4187d3-cells.csv.zip) contains Tower Cells localized by Unwiredlabs, but only ~20% localizied by Google Geolocation API

Comment: I tried several times and received back { "location": {
    "lat": 30.375936,
    "lng": -97.6945152
  },
  "accuracy": 1754
}

Comment: I suppose you used the Tower Cell data in the example. If so, the Tower Cell location that you report is certainly wrong. The "mobileCountryCode" (MCC) = 234 = United Kingdom. Your "lat": 30.375936, "lng": -97.6945152 pointing to Austin, Texas, United States. For testing purpose [cells.csv](http://download.micro-systems.it/download/fd599eaee4b4d81d15cae07c8b4187d3-cells.csv.zip) contains Tower Cells localized by Unwiredlabs, but only ~20% localizied by Google Geolocation API

Comment: The results found by ecg8 are probably explained in the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60213787/10060176
i.e. he does not have `Content-Type: application/json` in the headers, and thus the API was silently ignoring the body and resolving the IP address.
As to the original question: I found the same. Doesn't seem to be a user error.